# Why do I have two instances of the same partition in Nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, mount

Don't quite recall when this started behaving like this but Gnome's Nautilus has been reporting a sort of 'ghost' partition that's labeled the same as the regular one:

[image: screenshot]

The partition resides on a RAID1. Clicking on the 'ghost' partition provides:

```
mount: /dev/md127p1 already mounted or /media/Music_Library busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/md127p1 is already mounted on /media/Music_Library
```

My fstab:

```
# / was on /dev/sdh2 during installation
UUID=15bb606e-54af-4fa3-8341-12824a404dae /                       ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdh3 during installation
UUID=9eed87ee-f9d5-47c7-91e5-b82696142f7e /home                   ext4    defaults            0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdh4 during installation
UUID=27f06259-705d-48ba-83d6-3e1837a87198 none                    swap    sw                  0       0
# Music RAID
UUID=d10e627b-6068-4734-9111-5e2f71dbbe4f /media/Music_Library    ext4    auto,user           0       1
```

I'm running 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with fstab entries using UUID.

I solved it by replacing it with my equivalent to `/dev/md127p1`.

Try changing your fstab accordingly, reboot and see if the problem goes away like mine did.